# Understanding java hashmap and setting object's value

Tags: java, hashmap

I am migratimg an old visual basic application to Android and as I progressed I ran into some problems i can't solve. (I'm new to java)

In VB there is something called Dictionary and after googling the equivalent in java I come to the conclusion the thing to use is HashMap.

I need to create a HashMap with a string as key and an int[] as object:

```
HashMap<String, int[]> hm
```

So far, so good. I learned that after creating my int[]  I set the HashMap the following way...

```
int[] intArray = new int[23];
hm.put("myRandomString", intarray);
```

Now to the problem, how can I change the value on position x in my intArray?

I know I will use the key to find the intArray but anything I try  give me an error.

Comment: `intArray[x] = 4` for example.

Comment: Are you out of scope of `intArray`? Why do you need to get it back from the map?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, i can't set any positions at intArray on initialization

Comment: Future note: when you say "anything I try give me an error", actually show those things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
String someKey = "myRandomString";
int[] arrayFromMap = hm.get(someKey);
if (arrayFromMap != null) {
  arrayFromMap[x] = y;
```

Beyond that, you could/should use methods such as:

```
if (hm.contains(someKey))
```

or

```
if (arrayFromMap.length > x)
```

to check for all the possible things that could go wrong here. Also pay attention to details such as:

```
int[] oneArray = { 1, 2 , 3};
hm.put("a", oneArray);
hm.put("b", oneArray);
```

which adds the **same** array using two different keys. When you know do `get("a")` and manipulate the corresponding array, the value for "b" changes, too!

Comment: Thanks, just a quick follow up question, I don't need to "put it back" into the HashMap after inserting the new value, this will be handled automatic?

Comment: That is the point of my last paragraph: you have to understand what a *reference* is. In other words: a *reference* only points to an object. When you update the "pointed at object" you are good. So yes, it is enough to get() that array - any updates "go" to that one array.

Answer (score 2):

You first have to `get()` the array:

```
int[] arrToBeModified = hm.get("myRandomString");

arrToBeModified[0] = 123; // Do your modifications here.
```

Comment: You do not need to `put` it back. `get` gets you a live reference to the object (the array).

Comment: Hint: be careful about giving advise to others then. If you are not 98% sure about the content you are talking about - either dont talk about that, or make it clear in your posting where you are *speculating" yourself.